# CPU稼働率が定期的に0%になってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql, aws

サイトの応答が非常に悪くなるタイミングがあり、困っています。
頻度は1分に数回と多いです。

まだ公開して3日目なので、アクセスはほとんどありません。

`top`コマンドで確認してみると、そのタイミングだけCPUの`%`がプロセスすべて`0.0`になっているのです。
`load avarage`などに変化はなく、何を確認したら良いのかわかりません。

性能不足でしょうか。。。

今回始めて`aws`を触っていることもあり、戸惑っています。
確認すべきことがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

どうかよろしくお願いします。

---

環境

- ec2 t2.micro
- rails + unicorn + nginx + mysql(RDS)

---

```
# top
top - 00:17:50 up 28 days,  3:43,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:  78 total,   1 running,  77 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1020188k total,   957248k used,    62940k free,    28436k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   151028k cached

# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1020188     957000      63188         80      28468     151080
-/+ buffers/cache:     777452     242736
Swap:            0          0          0

# df 
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8123812 2541908   5481656  32% /
devtmpfs          500896      56    500840   1% /dev
tmpfs             510092       0    510092   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: どのようなサービスを行っているのでしょうか
また使用してるOSなど教えて下さい

Comment: サーバーの負荷が低いとのことですので、RDS 側の処理が重く、待ちになっているのではないでしょうか。RDS の負荷はどうですか？

Comment: ご使用の環境について詳細を教えて下さい。特にRDSのストレージの種類と容量が気になります。あと、CloudWatchで各種メトリクスを眺めて「非常に悪くなるタイミング」と相関関係がないか確認してください。できれば、詳細モニタリングを有効にして1分間隔のグラフが見られるようにするとなおよしです。あとRDSのSlowクエリログは見れますか？

Answer (score 2):

そのサイトが重いときのアクセスログが気になります。
アクセスログにレスポンスタイムは出力しているでしょうか？
Nginx だと log_format の `$request_time` で取得できます。参考: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

また、unicorn/rails で処理しているということなので、`$upstream_response_time` も気になります。もし出力していなければ、出力してみてください。

レスポンスタイムが短ければサーバの問題ではないということになります。
レスポンスに時間が掛かっている場合、`$upstream_response_time` の占める割合がどのくらいかによって、原因の所在が変わってきそうです。